# In Simulink, how do I add_block only if it doesn't exist already?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to use `add_block` from the Mask of a subsystem. The idea is to create a bunch of `From` tags at run time inside the subsystem. The problem is, the Mask Initialization window execustes multiple times even before the simulation starts. Since my code is in this initialization window, it tries to create multiple blocks of the same name, and gives me an error. As soon as I press OK on the Mask Editor!

Now, I do not want to use `MakeNameUnique`, because the copies created will be useless for me. Instead, is there any way I can ensure that `add_block` is executed *only* if a block of the desired name *doesn't* already exist?

Comment: For anyone reading this, I did eventually solve this. It's a hugely annoying solution, but you need to delete everything and essentially regenerate them at every instance.

Comment: Did you try using find_system to find existing instances?

Comment: The issue with using Find_System would be that I would need a check for _each_ From tag I want to create, and I have many of them. Clearing everything and starting from scratch looked like an easier to implement solution. I wish there was an option in add_block to add only in case it doesn't find existence. Me having to explicitly write code for it seems like a convoluted solution.